# How to save SpeechSynthesis audio to a Mp3 file in a UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, mp3, naudio

I'm working on a UWP TTS (Text to Speech) application and I'm having trouble saving speech to a file, preferably in Mp3 format. Does anyone know how to do this? In WPF, I used NAUDIO and NAUDIO.LAME, but unfortunately this does not seem to support UWP. I think I have to use Windows.Media.Transcoding API, but I didn't find any examples of how to do that. I found the code below in an article on MSDN, but it is not correct.

```
        StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            try
            {
                SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await WCSVariables.Synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(rtbText.Text);

                using (var reader = new DataReader(stream))
                {
                    await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                    IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer((uint)stream.Size);
                    await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageDialog msgdlg = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
                msgdlg.ShowAsync();
            }
```

********** UPDATE **********

After adding capabilities and file type associations for TXT and MP3, I was able to save the TXT files in any folder, but the MP3 files do not have the correct format. Files are created but do not play audio.

```
FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Mp3 Audio File", new List<string>() { ".mp3" });
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Document";

        StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (file.FileType == ".txt")
                {
                    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, rtbText.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    string path = file.Path.Remove(file.Path.IndexOf(file.Name), file.Name.Length);

                    StorageFolder mp3Folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
                    StorageFile mp3File = await mp3Folder.CreateFileAsync(file.Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                    SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await WCSVariables.Synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(rtbText.Text);

                    using (var reader = new DataReader(stream))
                    {
                        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                        IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer((uint)stream.Size);
                        await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(mp3File, buffer);
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageDialog msgdlg = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
                msgdlg.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a .mp3 file and then generate a speech audio stream from a basic text string. After that, write the stream to the file.

```
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.VideosLibrary;
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("MyVideo.mp3",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
if (file != null)
{
    try
    {
        var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
        SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello World");

        using (var reader = new DataReader(stream))
        {
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
            IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer((uint)stream.Size);
            await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);
        }
    }
    catch {}
}
```

Comment: MSFT, this StorageFolder causes an access permission error. I tried to include the reference to the broadFileSystemAccess capability, but it didn't resolve either. The only way I could make it work was by changing StorageFolder to ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, but that doesn't suit me. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to access VideosLibrary like above, you need to add “Videos Library” capability in the manifest instead of broadFileSystemAccess. The broadFileSystemAccess is used when you access the path of file.

Comment: Thanks @Faywang, In the case of the desktop application I'm working on, users have access to many folders besides Videos, Pictures and Music. How can I access these folders to save and recover files? In the Microsoft documentation, I found a recommendation for using the LocalCache folder, but how to use it with a FilePicker?

Comment: If you want to access other folders, you need to use `StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync()` method to get folder by passing it's path and declare broadFileSystemAccess capability or use FileOpenPicker. In addition, about the FileOpenPicker, it will open a dialog that similar to file explorer, then you could choose the file from the location you want and use it in your app. But it's not easy to find your LocalCache folder. So it's better not to use cache folder with picker. You can use `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.Path` to check where the cache folder is.

Comment: I added an UPDATE to the topic. Now I can save files in any folder, but the Mp3 format doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't use `WCSVariables` to generate speech output from a string but `var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();  SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("hello world");` and it can play audio. So you can try this method to see if the same issue occur.

Comment: Thanks @Faywang, it was a problem in file type association. It's working now.